# What exactly can Taskmaster copy?

Tags: marvel, the-taskmaster

What exactly can Taskmaster copy? For example, could he:

- copy a pregnant lady and get pregnant for only a short amount of time?
- copy non human things like animals?
- do accounting like a pro?
- make really hard sound effects after hearing them like a crane noise or something?

Comment: Taskmaster isn't a shapeshifter. :D He can't become pregnant or turn into an animal.

Comment: @OrangeDog Any reason you removed the character tag? It seems to be useful and character tags are okay as tags... especially on Marvel questions.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I had a look through meta and it seems to not qualify - an obscure character and only two (quite poor) questions.

Comment: @OrangeDog There is at least one more question on the character, it just wasn't tagged with it yet as the tag is quite new. The character has also had his own solo comic series and is set to appear in the upcoming _Black Widow_ film. On top of that there is an increased popularity on the character 2 questions recently (not much but is some) so I think the tag is quite useful and does seem to qualify as okay. (The quality of the questions shouldn't really factor into the decision to keep the tag or not).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot open a new discussion on Meta if you disagree. From what I can see specific character tags are discouraged except in exceptional circumstances.

Comment: @OrangeDog Character tags are treated differently depending on the containing universe. [marvel] and [dc] seem to like them but [game-of-thrones] not so much. Also as far as I can tell you're the only user who has disagreed with the tag versus 3 who want it (1 created it, 1 added it to another questions and myself). Therefore, I am adding the tag back in again. If you feel like it isn't needed I suggest you open a meta asking if we really do need it or not.

Answer (score 6):

Taskmaster's powers are generally described as [*photographic reflexes*](https://www.marvel.com/characters/taskmaster) in every comic with him that I've read. This generally means that he can mimic any action he sees, as soon as he sees it. It does not allow him to perform actions that he is not physically capable of performing.

For sound, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taskmaster_(comics)#Powers_and_abilities) has an un-cited example of him being able to mimic voices, so it may be possible. Given the stated way that his powers work, he would likely need to see a human(oid) with a similar vocal tract making a sound to be able to mimic it.

Watching an accountant would probably given him the enter numbers in spreadsheets like a pro, but not necessarily know what numbers he should enter (he does generally get some ability to predict the next moves of his opponents by copying them, but I think it would be a stretch to apply that here).

As with any comic book power, the exact nature of it is guaranteed to change a bit between writers and over time.

Answer (score -3):

This question was asked over on [Reddit and user neoblackdragon answered](https://www.reddit.com/r/Marvel/comments/4dh20u/what_exactly_can_taskmaster_do/d1qtvb9/) with:

> He can't perform a move that requires powers.
>
> So he sees Quicksilver running then he can learn his running technique but he'd never have super speed. If Quicksilver without powers has great running technique though then Taskmaster may benefit from it.

It has some other answers you might like to look at as well.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this user's theory is correct that you could [edit] in? Obviously at the moment this is none canon speculation of some reddit user.